# I want to exit back button app using willpopscope code with my code

Tags: flutter

I want to exit back button app using willpopscope code with my code.
Can't you write code like this?

When using another back button app exit code xxxx: xxxx error occurs.

And the code below also gives an error.

I'm looking for a way

Please advice

```
  class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final FirebaseUser user;
  HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{
        bool result = onPressBackButton();
        return await Future.value(result);
        },
      child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: MyHomePage(
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool onPressBackButton() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      scaffoldKey.currentState
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Tap back again to leave."),
        ));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WillPopScope widget is misplaced.

You have to place it inside the MaterialApp widget which have a Navigator to make it work.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      bool result = onPressBackButton();
      return await Future.value(result);
    },
    child: MyHomePage(),
  ),
);
```

}